# Why is this div/area scrolling right?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

I have a div/full width (to a point) slider, see here:

http://www.carboncandy.com/dev/avsl/

The static header works as intended, at least I assume it is.

However on resolutions lower than 1600 wide, the site scrolls to the right.

Ive checked everything I can and unless its staring me in the face and I cant see it im not sure what else to try?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because your image inside the `.slotholder` div has a width of 1820px.

Comment: And because your `#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper` has a width of `1600px`

Comment: How do I get the browser to ignore these and just display what it can rather than being scrollable?

Comment: @Wayners247  use % for Width and Height it (Its work on based screen resolution)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the issue..by adding the style

`body{overflow-x:hidden}`

Comment: @Wayners247 its working well..i had tested it..no other problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a fixed-width wrapping `div`, with a `overflow-x:hidden;` property. It will allow you to force the viewing area of the specific width you set it to.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Your Code -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width      : 1140px;
    overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

It's rather primitive, and promotes messy and redundant code. It's recommended that you find and fix the offending `div`s with the extra width, and fix the problem at it's root.